# PHP call from other class the parent methods from child

Tags: php

I've 3 classes in my project (connection , parent and child class).

Parent

```
class Upload {

   public function UploadFile(){
        /* some code */     
   } 
}
```

Child

```
class Photos extends Upload {

  public function getUrl(){
      /* some code */           
  } 

  public function UploadPhoto(){

     $this->getUrl();   

     $this->UploadFile();       
  } 
}
```

Now, I'd like to create a class that can use the methods of other classes.

```
Class Example {

private $db;
private $ph;

     public function __construct( Mysqliconn $db, Photo $ph) {

        $this->db = $db;    
        $this->ph = $ph;   
     } 

     public function callUploadPhoto() {

        $this->ph->UploadPhoto();
     }
}
```

instantiated in this way

```
$db = new Mysqliconn();
$ph = new Photos($db);
$ex = new Example($db, $ph);
```

My problem is that I can call the methods of other classes but not the method that refers to the parent class.
If I call **$ex->callUploadPhoto()** that calls **getUrl()** method of photos class but not the parent Upload method **Upload()**.
How could I do this? thanks

Comment: To call parent methods of the same class use `parent::someMethod()`

Comment: $this->somethod() and parent::someMethod() both will be the same in this case

Comment: I don't understand the question - Photo extends Upload. Through the inheritance mechanisms Photo has all the (non-private) methods of Upload, so that the call to $this->Upload in Photo should work as if you had implemented the function in Photo.  - one thing, though: in your example, you defined the function with a parameter ($name), but in the call you don't give a $name

Comment: should be pointed that technically the `Upload()` method is an old-style constructor for the Upload class.. that's asking for trouble..

Comment: @Ben How could I do this with "new-style" ? thank

Comment: @PaoloRossi If `Upload()` is *not* the Upload class constructor then maybe call it something else like `DoUpload()` (and update the code where it is called)

Comment: @Ben I hope I have understood what you told me, now I have edited my code, but unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: How do you know that `getUrl()` is called but `UploadFile()` *isn't* called in the `UploadPhoto()` method?

Comment: @Ben - Because getUrl return a value, while Upload file not upload the file. If I call this method (UploadPhoto()) from the child class works fine, from Example no.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40729/discussion-between-paolo-rossi-and-ben)

Answer (score 0):

try to use new **php 5.4.0 future** [traits](https://www.php.net/traits)

that can solve your problem very easily...

Comment: unfortunately I have to use php 5.3

Comment: @fruityp if we use traits then we can easily map that method... go and read documentation of traits unless down voting here

Comment: @Kalpit I know what traits are, the OP is not using them and this would be avoiding the problem s/he is encountering which does not contribute to the learning of PHP/OO concepts. Suggesting another method in this scenario is just avoiding the problem at hand which is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error you are getting?

and what is $name variable in  UploadPhoto function line 2 ie, $this->Upload($name)?

Comment: where is $name defined?

Comment: Why don't you write __construct to write constructor in the Upload class and try calling parent::__construct(); in Photos class?

Answer (score 0):

Your Example class needs to extend the Photos class. That fixes it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how I can extend. could you show me how? thanks